# Как включить FancyBox к полученному ранее HTML коду при исполнении этого скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Есть вот такой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/vasa666/aR22D/683/
Тут есть основной html код(назовем его ПЕРВЫЧНЫЙ) который далее обрабатывается при помощи FancyBox. и при исполнении скрипта, генерируется новый HTML(назовем его ВТОРИЧНЫЙ) который добавляется в конец страницы и именно он уже показывается пользователю.

Я попытался сразу выдать пользователю ВТОРИЧНЫЙ html код, но у меня не получается запустить FancyBox к сгенерированному html коду http://jsfiddle.net/vasa666/aR22D/685/ (моя попытка), как применить исполнение FancyBox к html коду который уже ранее был получен?
`<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/vasa666/aR22D/683/embed/"></script>`

Comment: Где вторичный код?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vasa666/aR22D/685/ - тут

Comment: Вы писали, что вторичный создается через первичный

Comment: Ну все правильно, есть основной HTML http://jsfiddle.net/vasa666/aR22D/683/ далее срабатывает FancyBox  который на основании кода, берет заголовок, фотку и описание, запихивает это все в DIV'ы и подгружает это все заново в конце страницы, перед закрывающим тегом </body>.

Comment: Проблема в чем?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vasa666/aR22D/685/ - запустить этот пример, чтоб он тянулся и срабатывал как этот: http://jsfiddle.net/vasa666/aR22D/683/